# Java client can't receive message from Mosquitto on Android

Tags: android, push-notification, mq, mqtt

1. My Os is Windows 7,32bit.
2. I install mosquitto-1.1.2-install-win32.exe.
3. I don't change the `mosquitto.conf` file，so no topic prefix setting.
4. Use Mosquitto to subscribe topic like(the subscription window):

   ```
   mosquitto_sub.exe -q 2 -t mytopic
   OR mosquitto_sub.exe -q 2 -t #
   ```
5. Use Mosquitto to publish a topic like(the publish window):

   ```
   mosquitto_pub.exe -q 2 -t mytopic -m “hello″
   ```
6. Then in the subscription cmd window,I can receive "hello"
7. I have been following Dale Lane's blog and "Android MQTT example project" to access Mosquitto.

   ```
   java client(MQTTDemo.java): 
   //i use mobile emulator
   editor.putString(“broker”, "10.0.2.2″); 
   editor.putString(“topic”, "mytopic”); 
   //or editor.putString(“topic”, “#”); '#' match any topic
   ```
8. I test `connectToBroker()` in `MQTTService.java`, the connection is OK.
9. I publish the topic "mytopic" again with Mosquitto.
10. But,finally I cannot receive the message in the mobile emulator.

    Anybody know why or any other methods?

    Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends at times on how the broker is configured.  There are ways within the Mosquitto broker to specify a topic prefix on a per-channel basis.  At other times, the subscription topic needs to be specified as generic.  I'm not sure if either of these apply in your situation, but there are easy diagnostics and you do not describe using them so I'll offer them as a starting point.

1. Easy way to tell is just to subscribe to `#` and then look at the topic strings that you receive.
2. Always have a separate subscription monitoring the broker.  For example, with WebSphere MQ I use the GUI to create a subscription to `#` before testing any publications.  If I get the publication in the GUI but not the app it points to a different problem set than if I don't get anything at all.

A better description of the problem will include some of this differential diagnostic.  If you get the chance, please re-test and edit the question with the results.

Comment: ：Thanks for your answer. I do some diagnostics:

Comment: with your advice i edit my question,i haven't used WebSphere MQ ago,it can work with Mosquitto ?

Comment: The WMQ GUI was just an example.  Yes, it works with Mosquitto but you are already doing something close to what I suggested.  Publishing to `#` won't work since a publication requires a fully qualified topic. The interesting question, which remains unanswered, is what happens when you are subscribed to `#` and publish using the emulator?

Comment: Thank you very much.
First I use "#" to subscribe any topic instead of publishing.
My question is: I use Mosquitto to publish a topic,and i can 
subscribe the topic successfully with Mosquitto too.Now i use
Mosquitto as server layer,and i make a android app following [Dale Lane's 
blog](http://dalelane.co.uk/blog/?p=1599) as app layer,but with 
the android app i can't sucessfully subscibe the topic which is published on the Mosquitto.

I am not sure whether my problem was well explained?

Comment: The problem was well explained, but I'm not seeing the diagnostic. The question at hand is "what is seen when you are subscribed with the Android *and* something else, where both subs are subscribed to `#`?  With WMQ I can look at the MQTT channel and see whether the Android is attached, what its subscription is, etc.  I don't think Mosquitto has that ability so I'm trying to discover where the problem is by differentiating between a known-working thing and the non-working thing.  So far I see these two things tested, but at different times.

Comment: Thanks Rob, I will do more diagnostic.